# Transferring my site on Apache server to AWS

Tags: php, mysql, apache, amazon-web-services

I've developed a site in PHP using xampp's Apache and MySQL servers. I didn't keep the prospect of hosting it in AWS in my mind and so I was wondering how much should I change my site to host it on AWS. And I wish to change it as little as possible.

Can someone point me to a definitive guide to AWS site hosting of a php site that's developed for Apache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So long as your PHP code is well written, it should be pretty portable. There is no definitive guide that I know about for XAMPP->AWS deployments, but you should find it pretty easy to spin up an EC2 instance and test your app before public launch. Is there some aspect in particular that you are worried about in terms of the migration, or is it just a general concern? If it's just a general concern i.e. you just haven't done it before, keep in mind that you can easily destroy and re deploy your AWS server, so I would recommend that you just give it a go and then come back here and post any errors that you run into... also the guys over at https://serverfault.com/ (don't worry, it's affiliated with Stack Overflow) might be better placed to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It has less to do with XAMPP => AWS, and more to do with:

1. Which OS are you moving from/to?
2. Which generation of PHP are you moving from/to?

AWS services like Elastic Beanstalk and OpsWorks use Amazon Linux as their base OS (related to CentOS and RHEL), but with raw EC2, there are tons of different supported OS's (e.g., Ubuntu, Slackware, Fedora, Debian, CentOS, Amazon Linux). In both cases, you have full root access to the machines.

Also, make sure you're using the same generation of PHP (e.g., 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, HHVM) between your current server and the AWS server. This will prevent things like language/syntax differences between the two environments.

Like Nicholas Byfleet said, "So long as your PHP code is well written, it should be pretty portable."